# Common utility for different container

Tags: python, docker, containers, lxc, jail

I am looking for a common utility in python that can be used to operate for different container types like jails, docker, lxc etc based on OS and user needs

For example : when user selects docker in config and creates a container using this utility, then an instance gets created  within docker environment

Do we have something of this sort existing?

Comment: There is OCI image spec in purpose of unifying image format. An OCI image can be easily used by different container environment. See https://github.com/opencontainers/image-spec

Comment: Thanks Yuankun. OCI looks to be standardizing image format. What i am looking for is a framework or utility that runs as wrapper around different container technologies. The reason for ask is, we want to use "jail" when logged inside FreeBSD, use "docker, lxc" when logged inside linux.